# Padding numeric on SQL SYBASE

Tags: sql, padding, sybase

I have a numeric field like `1,3065` and I need that to became like this: `000000000000000130`.

I mean 16 integers and 2 decimals, without the comma, adding 0es to the left and, if needed, to the right.

Is there any way to do that with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work in Sybase:

```
select right(replicate('0', 16) + cast(cast(field*100 as int) as varchar(255)), 16)
```

Comment: what if I need an approximation instead that a truncate?

Comment: @abierto . . . The easiest way is to replace `cast(field*100 as int)` in the above with `cast(field*100 + 0.5 as int)`.  You could also use the `round()` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select REPLICATE('0',16-len(cast(cast((1.3065*100) as int) as varchar(16))))+cast(cast((1.3065*100) as int) as varchar(16))
```

Result of above select:

```
0000000000000130
```

If you want approximation you should use `FLOOR` or `CEILING` function as below

```
declare @multiplier int

select @multiplier = 1000

select REPLICATE('0',16-len(cast((floor(1.3065*@multiplier)) as varchar(16))))+cast(floor(1.3065*@multiplier) as varchar(16))
```

Result of above select:

```
0000000000001306
```

You can change an approximation by changing `@multiplier`. For example if you want result from 1st query you should change `@multiplier` to `100`.